# Rails - Strange time_select buggy behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, activerecord

My rails repo example is here:
https://github.com/johndel/strange_timeselect

The replication of the strange behavior can be shown here:
https://captain24.herokuapp.com/availabilities/new

I have the following problem with `time_select`: 
In a new rails app with postgresql, I have a model (`availabilities`) with a `started_at` column which is of type `time` in postgres. When I create a new record, it saves the `started_at` value, one hour before than the selected. On the update it works correctly.

I noticed the following:
I can replicate it only on heroku (locally I cannot replicate it). It works only on create and only after I set `default_timezone` on `application.rb` as you can see on this [commit](https://github.com/johndel/strange_timeselect/commit/43ab2bbc3d8d562588f3492973a6a97a7c4be6d2).

The application has also another model named `tasks` with a column named `started_at` and type `datetime`. This one works always correct but it saves the time on different timezone than the `time` field of `availabilities`.

I can fix it if I add `ignore_date: true` on the time_select field, but I am wondering why is this happening? Is it normal and I am missing something? Or is it some very strange ruby or rails bug? Or is it an issue / misconfiguration with postgresql on heroku?

**Update:**
Because **@max** asked me to explain the code further, here it goes:

Regarding the code, right now it is just two scaffold resources with the commands `rails g scaffold tasks started_at:datetime` and `rails g scaffold availabilities started_at:time`. So one is `tasks` and the other is `availabilities` with only one column each model. I have also added in the `config/application.rb` these lines of code:

```
config.time_zone = 'Athens'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

The code of availabilities form is this (plain scaffold):

```
<%= form_with(model: task, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :started_at %>
    <%= form.time_select :started_at %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The code of migration for availability is this:

```
class CreateAvailabilities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :availabilities do |t|
      t.time :started_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If you add the above code and deploy on heroku, you will be able to reproduce the problem.

So regarding the problem with the above code is that when I am creating an `availability` record, it keeps one hour less than what it is selected. This happens only on create. It isn't the case with `task` record so it probably has to do with `time` postgres type, with the `active_record` timezone. this happens only on heroku as you can check on the link above.

Comment: Its really hard to make anything meaningful out of  text that describes what code does. And it really just creates more questions. Instead try to create a minimal verifiable example that reproduces the behavior you are talking about. And no - adding a link to your github repo is not the same thing.

Comment: I think it is pretty straightforward what I am asking. I have the live code to reproduce the bug without any effort as well as the code on repository (it is just 3 commits so it is very easy to understand what changed). So I am asking, is the above behavior right and expected and I am doing something wrong (and what that is) or should we put a ticket on rails repository because it is a bug?

Comment: You might think so but your not really helping us rule out anything and asking the reader to dig through your code to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Ok I will add more explaination.

Comment: Not explaination. Add real code to the question. It's not that hard.

Comment: I added the 4 lines of code which are responsible, the files that you will find them and exactly what they do. I haven't write any custom code except from these 4 lines. All the others are plain scaffold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214012/discussion-between-johndel-and-max).

Comment: Why are you not using UTC? What are you trying to solve by having a non-standard server time?

Comment: You mean why I am using `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` , so why I am converting the time from UTC to local when I am saving to database? Good point there is no reason but even when I remove this, the bug is still the same. Even with this line, it doesn't make sense this behavior (it would make sense if that happened both on create and update).

Comment: try to use `byebug` in your create action and check the format of the `started_at` param in the `availability_params`. does it reflect the correct time in your OS ? is it behind the time by one hour ?

Comment: @AbdullahFadhel It sends the correct time on this format: `"started_at(1i)"=>"2020", "started_at(2i)"=>"5", "started_at(3i)"=>"19", "started_at(4i)"=>"01", "started_at(5i)"=>"16"`. It doesn't seem like a form problem.

Comment: in this link: https://nandovieira.com/working-with-dates-on-ruby-on-rails, you will find a section called `How dates are persisted` read it if you did not and check if configuring  `time with time zone`  for the `time` type will fix the error:
`config/initializers/active_record.rb`
`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::`
`NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:time] = {name: "timestamp with time zone"}`

Comment: Can you share the logs/production.log file?

Comment: @AbdullahFadhel Instead of telling me what to read, can you write an explanation why this is happening only on create and not on update if it isn't a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different problems.

1) Different scenario in local vs Heroku.
 - Your schema.rb file has "started_at" listed as datetime, while in the migration, it is "time"
 - Heroku runs the migration, but `bin/rails db:setup` loads from schema.rb, hence you don't see the problem locally as it's saved as datetime.

2) 
The problem with the time column is that with a lack of date, Ruby has to guess. When you are creating a new record, the form is prefilled with the current date, which at the time of the post, is in May (a summer month), and will be parsed in EEST. 
Incoming attributes `"2020", "05", "20", "11", "00"` will be parsed as `Wed, 20 May 2020 11:00:00 EEST +03:00`

This is then saved in the database as time offset by -3 hours `8:00:00`

When it is next loaded from the database, there's no date attached, so Rails parses it with the date assumption of `"2000", "01", "01"` , which results in `Sat, 01 Jan 2000 10:00:00 EET +02:00`. Note that only two hours is added in this case, since it's EET.

When you edit, the form is prefilled with the availability's current started_at `Sat, 01 Jan 2000 10:00:00 EET +02:00`. When you update, since date from the form is now January, it is parsed using EET time zone and saves now. Since the date used to display and edit is the same, it now looks 'correct'

How to fix? It depends on the application, and I'm no expert, but some thoughts:-

1) Some would say that time inherently has no meaning without date. Perhaps you could consider using datetime column instead. 12PM availability in Greece may mean differently to people in different time zones.

2) You could use something like the `tod` gem to handle time.

3) You could store it as an integer offset from say, 12AM.

Answer (score 5):

This is occurring because you need to take your server's timezone into account.
You need to configure Heroku as well.The command to change Heroku Time settings is something like below

`heroku config:add TZ="Europe/Paris"`

And it not a good idea to save date in any other format than UTC

[Details](http://www.samir-el-maoujoudi.com/code/2018/10/12/how-to-handle-time-zones-in-rails.html)

**EDIT**

To answer the question why the update method is working differently, you have to inspect the form rendered by rails.Rails creates additional three hidden fields

`availability[started_at(1i)]`,

`availability[started_at(2i)]` and

`availability[started_at(3i)]`

On the create form, those fields have default values of 2020,5,19

But on the edit form, they have the value of 2000,1,1

My educated guess is they are messing up with the daylight saving time, and thus creating the anomaly.

Comment: I agree regarding the part of not saving the time on not UTC. But why is this happening on create and not on update?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check :)